# Audio volume only decreases for a few seconds

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio, timeline

When I click on “sound” settings, I can see that I can adjust volume from 1 to for example 0.200. However, when I do that, it only remains 0.200 for one or a few frames max and then returns back to 1.000. How can I change the volume of the whole audio? I have tried clicking on “animate properly” to the right of “volume”, but it didn’t help.
Also, “pitch” works just fine - I can change it once for the whole audio.